# How to load Rail dataset from nlme library

Tags: r, dataset

I just started to do my first steps in R respectively I'm reading a book to do so and I fail at the second page..
"The data on the rails experiment are given in an object called Rail that is available with the nlme library. Giving the name Rail by itself to the interpreter will result in the data being displayed."

By applying this I receive:

> Rail
>   Error: object 'Rail' not found

I ensured that nlme is installed so what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Alternatively, load the package: `library(nlme)` then you'll have access.

Comment: If nlme is not loaded, `nlme::Rail`

Comment: Fine, it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This couldn't be simpler. Note that R is case sensitive.

```
data(Rail, package = "nlme")
```

or

```
library(nlme)
data(Rail)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get to assign your data to a local variable. The package needs to be loaded;

```
mydata <- get(anydata, asNamespace('<package_name>'))
```

In your case it's going to be this:

```
library(nlme)
rail <- get("Rail", asNamespace("nlme"))
```

And the data will be stored in the variable called `rail`.

Also you can simply do this if you want it as the same name as its name in the package:

```
data(Rail)
```

Comment: `data()` is designed to load package datasets. This is reaching your for your pocket around your back.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I was adding to my answer actually. That was a workaround in case you want a different name for your dataset.